# auth005 error when attempting to send an email using php on xampp server

Tags: php, html, xampp

Im currently using xampp to test my php code for forms. im trying to email the form to my email when submitted. i have edited the sendmail.ini and php.ini, ive also tried using laragon and still received errors. when i check the sendmail error page in my xampp i get this back 20/04/21 16:28:07 : (#AUTH005) Too many bad auth attempts. after running my php code on the local server.

```css
input[type=text], select, textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  resize: vertical;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}
```

```html
  <form action="action_page.php" method="post">
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">

   <label for="email">Email</label>
 <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email..">

    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
    <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

```
    <?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$firstname = $lastname = $email = $comment = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $firstname = test_input($_POST["firstname"]);
  $lastname = test_input($_POST["lastname"]);
  $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
  $subject = test_input($_POST["subject"]);
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>

<?php
echo "<h2>Your Information:</h2>";
echo $firstname;
echo "<br>";
echo $lastname;
echo "<br>";
echo $email;
echo "<br>";
echo $subject;
echo "<br>";
?>
<?php
// the message
$msg = "New contact submission";

// use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters
$msg = wordwrap($msg,70);

// send email
mail("websiteforms.mccomasinsurance@yahoo.com","form sub.",$msg);
?>

sendmail.ini
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=465
smtp_ssl=ssl
error_logfile=error.log
auth_username=myemail
auth_password=
pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=
force_sender=
force_recipient=
hostname=localhost

php.ini
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
;SMTP=localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
;smtp_port=25
...
sendmail_from = myemail
....
sendmail_path ="C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

When developing locally, email testing is a recurring problem. Setting up a sendmail server, especially on Windows, is not a straightforward thing; it also leads to a number of problems when you want to use an external SMTP. I see that you have configured Google's SMTP server; but this is definitely a problem, for several reasons. One of many, that you locally can't have a valid, recognized SSL certificate, but only a self-generated and locally signed certificate from your PC, for testing purposes. So it will certainly be rejected by every server on the Internet.

My advice is to use a small local server, when developing on your own PC, to test email sending.
I use [MailSlurper](http://mailslurper.com). It is very simple and, once started, it allows you to see a panel with the received emails on `http://localhost:8080`.

Try to install MailSlurper, disable the SendMail from php.ini and set php.ini with correct protocol, smtp host and port. In my local configuration I have this kind of email sending setting:

```
protocol = 'smtp';
smtp_host = 'localhost';
smtp_port = 2500;
starttls = FALSE;
```